# Write a program that will count the total number of words in a file in c

Tags: c, arrays, memory-leaks, word-count

I am starting to learn C and I have to write a program that will count the number of words in a file.  I don't know the size of the file, so how can I declare an array without knowing the size?  I know that the `number_of_words` is not given, but what should I do?
(In my code I should not use `fgets` or `EOF` according to assignment instructions)

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    char* word[] = {"/usr/bin/ls", "-1", NULL};
    int number_of_words;
    int i;
    word = malloc (number_of_words * sizeof(char));
    FILE* f = fopen (argv[1], "r");
    fscanf(f, "%s", &word);
    if ( f == NULL) {
        return -1; 
    }

    for (i = 0; word[i] != NULL; i++) {
        return i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have to save the words or just count them? If you're only counting, you don't need an array.

Comment: This is part of the assignment. The other part I will have to write a program that will count the number of occurrences of each unique word in a file and then find the most frequent pair of words and then the most frequent quads, so I will need to save the words.

Comment: Your code tells me you are lost in the weeds. Try to get some one on one time with your prof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this sort of problem, as I understand it from a little bit of a compilers course, you should grow your array dynamically—*malloc* your choice of starting size, track how full it is, and *realloc* if it gets full.

I'd echo Bing Bang's feeling that the prof may be able to guide you in the right direction. I've found my profs helpful.